# Voting between classifiers : How to prove it works?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, ensemble-learning, voting-system

Assume $m$ independent binary classifiers with probability $p$ to be correct $p>0.5$. Show that the probability of a voting, e.g. decision is made by the majority of classifiers is correct with probability $q>p$.

I think this problem as equivalent to showing that the Binomial cumulative distribution $\text{CDF}(k,n,p)$ follows $\text{CDF}(k=\frac{m}{2},m,p)<1−p$.

Tried to use Markov's inequality but failed. After some numerical experimenting, I first found out this work only for odd $m$. For example, if $m = 4$ and $p = .6$ voting will have a worse performance ($q < p$) ($q = 0.4752 < .6$). For odd $m$ I verified numerically the claim is correct but find it hard to prove.

The challenge is to show a bound on the Binomial distribution $\text{CDF}$ which is tight enough to be compared with $p$. When I tried the Markov inequality, $P(x > a) < \dfrac{E(x)}{a}$, I get a bound which is not tight enough. This is demonstrated in the figure below:
[image: bounds vs. real CDF]
Code which created this figure in Python:

```py
    p = np.linspace(0.5,1, 100);
    n = 5
    p_error = binom.cdf(k=n/2, p=p, n=n)
    hoeffding = np.exp(-2*(n*p-n/2)**2/n)
    chernoff = np.exp(-2*(n*p-n/2)**2/n/p)
    def bernoli_dkl(a,p):
        return a*np.log(a/p) + (1-a)*np.log((1-a)/(1-p))
    dkl = np.exp(-n*bernoli_dkl(1/2,p))
    plt.figure(figsize=(3,3), dpi=150)
    plt.plot(p, 1-p_error, label='correct')
    plt.plot(p, 1-hoeffding, label='hoeffding')
    plt.plot(p, 1-chernoff, label='chernoff')
    plt.plot(p, 1-dkl, label='dkl')
    plt.plot(p, p, label='p')
    plt.ylabel('$p_{correct}$')
    plt.xlabel('$p$')
    plt.title('$n={}$'.format(n))
    plt.legend()
```

Where the bounds where taken from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds